# How to place all chapter titles on verso pages in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, context, double-sided, context-mkiv

I need to set all of the chapters within a document to begin on the verso, or left-hand pages. How can I get ConTeXt to add a blank page before each chapter title if the chapter title does not appear on a verso page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First define a page break:

```
\definepagebreak
  [chapterpagebreak]
  [yes, left]
```

Then set up the chapters to use this new defined page break:

```
\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [page=chapterpagebreak]
```

More information on the [ConTeXt wiki - definepagebreak](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definepagebreak) and [Truly empty pagebreak before chapters](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Titles#Truly_empty_pagebreak_before_chapters).